# Cannot use the answer button on any stackexchange site anymore since site upgrade

Tags: discussion, firefox

I apologize in advance if I'm in the wrong forum but I wanted to post an answer to my own question but everytime I click the answer my own question button it does absolutely nothing. All other buttons seem to work fine.

I'm currently using Firefox 45.9.0 ESR for Linux (Slackware 13). I don't want to redo my entire computer just for one button to work and everything else is running fine. In fact, I also use older software on my computer that relies on older hardware (like the old parallel port). Yes, I make custom hardware.

Without having to resort to buying another computer or attempting to upgrade to Slackware 14 with a good chance of breaking old software and without having to go to the less reliable software, Microsoft windows, is there anything else I can do at my end to make the button work?

I also tried Chrome but it would not install on my computer. The only other browser I use is Opera 11 but many sites including this one no longer work with it because of the message "Unable to complete secure transaction". The same kinds of errors happen when I use Seamonkey and Konqueror browser.

The only way I could get an opportunity to answer my question is if I write one and before I submit it I check the box next to "answer your own question".

So what can I do to get this behaviour to work on my computer without having to reinstall everything? Is there any firefox setting I can apply in about:config to get this site to work properly?

UPDATE

I am using Seamonkey 2.40 for linux to make this update. I was able to clock "edit" under my question to add this content, but if I click the "add a comment" or "answer my question" button, none of those buttons do anything.

Comment: You are aware that Stack Exchange only supports supported browsers?  45.9 is not the current ESR release.

Comment: hm. While unsupported, this smells off - if he can post a question, why can't he ask a question?

Comment: I think your meant self-answer not ask :) Note that 15 rep is required to self-answer. Which isn't the case for the OP

Comment: @mike What question on what site are you trying to answer?

Comment: Hmm, pressing "Answer your question" button seems to call a Javascript function to show a pop-up dialog. Pressing "Add a comment" will also call a Javascript function to show the comment form. Perhaps the script is broken on these browsers?

Comment: Seamonkey 2.40 is based on an even older version of Gecko (43) than your Firefox version (45.9)... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaMonkey#Release_history

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old and unsupported browser. As a result performance and functionality is not guaranteed. It might work but there isn't much we can do. I appreciate that this is not helpful, but it is impossible to guarantee support for old and out-of-date software.

As a minimum it is advisable to not be using out-of-date browsers or operating systems to navigate the public internet due to the prevalence of malware and vulnerabilities. If you cannot update this machine then you should use another computer or mobile phone.

If you have Javascript disabled you may also experience loss of functionality.

From Meta Stack Exchange: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

> ### Which browsers are supported?
>
> **We support the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use**. This does not
> include beta/dev releases, which are not supported.
>
> The supported browsers, in practice, based on the above guideline:
>
> - **Standard View**
> - Firefox ([current version status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_release_history) from Wikipedia)
>
>   - Current and ESR versions are supported.
> - Chrome ([current version status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_release_history)
>   from Wikipedia)
> - Opera ([current version status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser)
>   from Wikipedia)
>
>   - Presto-based Opera is not supported
> - Safari ([current version status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) from
>   Wikipedia)
>
>   - Exception: Safari on Windows
> - Edge ([current version status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge#Release_history)
>   from Wikipedia)
> - **Mobile View**
> - Chrome for Android
>
>   - Supported: Last 2 versions
> - Mobile Safari (iPhone browser)
>
>   - Supported: last 2 versions.